# How to get result from query group by sql without return duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates, left-join

i have 3 table that will join into 1 table.

table1

```
id|prdct_name|qty
001     A      5
002     B      5
003     C      5
```

table2

```
id|prdct_id|price
 1    001    100
 2    001    200
 3    002    150
 4    002    250
```

table3

```
id|prdct_id|stock_in|stock_out
 1   001      5           0
 2   001      10          0
 3   002      15          0
 4   002      25          0
```

I have tried this sql (updated due to typo)

```
select a.prdct_name as Name, a.qty as QTY,b.price as PRICE, c.stock_in as SIN,c.stock_out as SOUT
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.id=b.prdct_id 
left join table3 c on a.id=c.prdct_id
where 1=1 group by b.id,c.id
```

but result return duplicate like this table

```
NAME|QTY|PRICE|SIN|SOUT
 A    5   100   5    0
 A    5   100   10   0
 A    5   200   5    0
 A    5   200   10   0
 B    5   150   15   0
 B    5   150   25   0
 B    5   250   15   0
 B    5   250   25   0
```

the result should be

```
 NAME|QTY|PRICE|SIN|SOUT
 A    5   100   5    0
 A    5   200   10   0
 B    5   150   15   0 
 B    5   250   25   0
```

is there a way to remove the duplicate issue? trying with distinct also not help.
Thanks

Comment: . . You are joining on name to id.  No results should match in the second and third tables.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff sorry it was typo, when i try i use id instead name but still result duplicate

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add *SOLVED* to your question title or to edit a solution into the question. You've indicated it's been solved by accepting an answer to the question, which everyone can see. If you want to add details of the solution that are not in that  answer, write another answer and post that solution using the space below in the answer section to do so. See [Can I answer my own question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the SQL keyword `DISTINCT` to select non-duplicate rows.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  prdct_name as NAME,
  qty as QTY,
  price as PRICE,
  stock_in as SIN,
  stock_out as SOUT
FROM
  table1 a
INNER JOIN
  table2 b ON a.id=b.prdct_id
LEFT JOIN
  table3 c ON b.id=c.id
GROUP BY
  a.id, c.id
```

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfffcf/12)

More about *DISTINCT* [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

Comment: hi @martin, i edited your fiddle with changed table3.prdct_id to table3.id and my problem is solved..please check (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfffcf/12)

Comment: Edited the answer to fit the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your second `join` should be on `id` -- and your `join` conditions don't look right anyway.

```
select a.prdct_name as Name, a.qty as QTY, b.price as PRICE, c.stock_in as SIN,c.stock_out as SOUT
from table1 a left join
     table2 b
     on a.id = b.prdct_id left join
     table3 c 
     on a.id = c.id
where 1=1
group by b.id, c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

change your join key it should id =product_id but you are trying with name & product_id

```
select a.prdct_name as Name, a.qty as QTY,b.price as PRICE, c.stock_in as SIN,c.stock_out as SOUT
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.id=b.prdct_id 
left join table3 c on a.id=c.prdct_id
where 1=1 group by b.id,c.id
```

Comment: hi @fa06 sorry it was typo, i use id instead name but still result duplicate,please check my update question

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187b92/5 check here - it does not give duplicate records

Comment: your example fiddle its working, but i need to clarify that table 2 and 3 is dinamyic and table 1 is static. if i insert new value to table 2 and 3 then ur example not working anymore...please check here [link sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfffcf/1/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfffcf/1/0)

Comment: in table 2 and 3 i add product B with price 250 but not showing in result

Comment: hi @fa06 thanks for your help... it's solved...please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfffcf/12